# Excel 2013 js API: How to get Worksheet names?

Tags: office365, office365api, office-js, office365-apps

How can I get the name of different sheets within an Excel workbook using the js API of Microsoft.

For Excel 2016 I use ctx.workbook.worksheets.items but is there something when developing add ins for Excel 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. To get the host-specific functionality (as opposed to the cross-host APIs of 2013, that didn't got into nearly as much depth for any given host), you will need Office 2016.